# How to extract text and set as variable Batch Code CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find

I would like to extract what users are online based on this text file:
https://minecraft-statistic.net/en/server/167.114.43.185_25565/json/

I will save it as a text file. Inside that there is something:

> ```
> "players_list":["Raskhol"]["Lukaka"],"map":...etc
> ```

I would like to extract all the text between `"_list":` and `,"map"` and set it as a variable. So that when I call the variable `%Playerlist%`, it would say:

> ```
> ["Raskhol"]["Lukaka"]
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

similar to @geisterfurz007's answer, this one assumes the you are after the first instance of "players_list": before the first instance of ,"map"

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P var=<some.json
Set var=%var:,"map"=&:%
Set var=%var:*"players_list":=%
Echo=%var%
Timeout -1
```

Comment: This worked excellent! I will test this out and see if I can customize it too. Dont abandon this, I may be back with another question. Thanks Compo and geister..ETC

Answer (score 0):

Not tested due to beeing on phone.

```
@echo off
For /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%g in (PathTo\file.txt) do (
Set var=%%g
Goto:next
)
:next
Set var=%var:,map=%
echo %var%
```

Assumes players are the first to be listed.

Reads the file, takes the part after the first `:` up to the second one, stores it in `var`.
Then `,map` gets replaces with nothing to result in just the players beeing `echo`ed in the end.

Feel free to ask questions if something is unclear! Might take a while as I am currently mobile though.

Comment: That returned: '101664, "ip"'

Comment: Thats because of the way I split the string. You could adjust the number after `tokens` to fit the thing. Compos answer is by far more elegant and not able to fail.