# Extract text from text file, produces error Batch file

Tags: batch-file, text-files, extract

Recently I posted something that extracts text from a text file ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999469/how-to-extract-text-and-set-as-variable-batch-code-cmd)), now what I am trying to do is extract everything from `[` to `]` in my script which pings any server but it just keeps returning `]=` instead of the Ip address. I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out why... anyone know?

```
echo Enter Minecraft Server Address:
set /p ad=">"
ping "%ad%" /n 1 >test.txt
Set/P var=<test.txt
Set var=%var:]=&:%
Set var=%var:*[=%
Echo=%var%
```

(Returns `]=`)

thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably `var` is empty. (Actually I am sure about that.) `ping` returns an empty line at first, so you might need to read the second one: `< test.txt (set /P var= & set /P var=)`. You should perhaps also consider the case when the output of `ping` does not contain `[`/`]` (when an IP is given)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need to use the same method:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P "ad=Enter Minecraft Server Address > "
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%A In ('Ping -n 1 "%ad%"') Do Set "var=%%A"
Echo=%var%
Timeout -1
```